# Eclipse error: NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ref/FinalReference

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I've installed Eclipse for android and that works okay. When I try to start a java-file I got the following error: Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ref/FinalReference

After some research I know it was something with buildpass but after trying I didn't got it to work. I removed it all (Eclipse, Java, Android) and reinstall everything but with the same disapointing result. Could somebody explain to me what to do because what I tried from the internet didn't work for me.

Comment: same problem i m also having....android applications are working fine...but java file are giving error NoClassDefFoundError...

Comment: Are you trying to "run" an Android java file? How are you getting this error?

Comment: Try creating a Java project instead of an Android project and try to run the Java file there and see what happens.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Find Running configurations -> java application
2. In the new configuration's Classpath tab, find "Android Library" under Bootstrap Entries and remove it.
3. Still in the Classpath tab, select Bootstrap Entries and click the Advanced button.
4. Choose Add Library and click OK.
5. Select JRE System Library and click Next.
6. Select Workspace Default JRE and click Finish.

Based on http://www.frickingnutz.com/files/android_pdf/FAQs.pdf

Comment: Wow... someone knew a lot about Eclipse there

Answer (score 2):

I have been frustrated by this error for several days, by comparing with my colleagues Eclipse  preferences with mine, the problem was fixed by changing the Java compliance level from 1.7 to 1.6.
This will also change the generated .class files and source compatibility to 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried running a specific java class, then every time you click the run button it will default to whatever you tried to run last.

Click the drop down beside the run button and choose specifically what you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "run configuirations" under the "run" menu. Select the delete run menu. Do  a clean and then you should be back and running again.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use all the answers above but it doesn´t work.

This error happened when I wrote 1 method that returned a `String [][]` ( don't know why yet) but the error doesn't disappear when I disable (`/*   */`) the method.

Finally I did 2 things:

1. Created a new Android Project and copy the files. rebuild the Activity.java and the manifest.xml.

   It worked until I activate the method then the same error all over again:

   `VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ref/FinalReference
   and then`

   Error occurred during initialization of VM and no matter what I do, it didn´t work until I create another Android Project.
2. So the 2nd thing I did was :

   Run-> Run Configurations->Java Application and click on New_Configuration then I clicked on the red X above (Delete selected launch configuration) and it worked ( not the method but the program worked when I `/*   */` it.)

Comment: another thing : my error was that I have a main( ) method in the utilities.java file.  That generated the error plus I run the app when I have the utilities.java in my screen