# eclipse is being very unstable

Tags: eclipse

I keep getting this error

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ref/FinalReference

There are no main methods in my code and that is the only reason i received it before. Why is this occurring. I cant show you a log because it crashed before loading up any code.

I am wondering if its anything today with the Galaxy tab add on. I have used android version 10 and built a complete piece of software and haven't had any problems with it.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this has anything to do with "stable" or not. It's not crashing, and the error you get is not intermittent, so I guess it's more your problem than Eclipse's. Maybe change the title of the question a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9455236/60462

Comment: its not a duplicate its different. The other person has just installed there project. I have been building projects for months. Also it works fine with android I only seem to have problems with Galaxy tab add on. java files are running fine its android files running galaxy tab add on which seem to be having problems.

Comment: Does your project's Java Build Path have its JRE set correctly?

Comment: Is it *Eclipse* that's unstable, or your app?

Comment: to answer your question. I am not sure the app is built on a similar premises to an earlier app which had no difficulties. Also when i run java programs they dont have this problem at all. Therefore I think its either eclipse or a plugin i am using in android.

Comment: could you explain more about checking the java build path

Comment: its working i think it was something to do with the galaxy add on

Comment: I am wondering is it better to use eclipse in a Linux installation.