# Adding the contents from XML to Java

Tags: java, android, xml

I have been reading this tutorial - 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

and I got a problem... In the tutorial they explain the XML elements (TextField and Button) and in the end they say how to tun the program to see the button + the text field.
The problem is, that the emulator doesn't show them.. just a black screen.
I guess it's because I haven't added anything to the .java main file, but in the tutorial nothing was mentioned about it.
What should I do?
Thanks **a lot** for everyone who will help!

Comment: What are the contents of the main Java file? It should, by default, have an `onCreate` method with a `setContentView(...)` call. If it doesn't, that'll be what's missing...

Comment: @RoniCopul Edit your question and add the code here, instead of trying to put it in a comment.

Comment: @DavidConrad I sent a link to the code below the answer (one of the last comments)

Answer (score 0):

If your XML file name is `main.xml` then to display it content you need this method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working... I don't know what's the problem

Comment: Please, add the code of your Activity which is located in .java file

Comment: adding the code is a mess in a comment (because the <code> tag can't be used :/) so I'll just say that he code is the same as you said

Comment: Yep, the code looks good. What about `activity_main.xml`? Have you added the elements there or to another file?

Comment: My main XML file is activity_main.xml,(found in res/layout)  and it's also uses a strings.xml file, that found in values/values

Comment: Do you have only one .java file or there is another activity?

Comment: If your XML file is `activity_main.xml`, try using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` instead.

Comment: @vasart Only one.. 
But something weird error showed up in the console, I think it may be because the string.xml and activity_main.xml are in different directories

Comment: @Soxxeh That's what is written ;)

Comment: `activity_main.xml` is a layout and it should be in `res/layout` folder. And `strings.xml` is a values file and it should be in `res/values`.

Comment: Can you give a link to an archive with your project?

Comment: Main.java - http://pastebin.com/1KYdz4EJ 
<br />XML files - http://pastebin.com/cAUf17RV

Comment: You have an error in `activity_main.xml`. Button has property `layout_width` set to `wrap_cont*a*nt`, but should be `wrap_cont*e*nt`

Comment: Still not working.. I think the problem is in the VM, because when I press "Run" the Eclipse writes "Error occurred during initialization of VM<br />
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ref/FinalReference"

Comment: (Until now I opened the emulator through the list by pressing "Start..." because it didn't work by the "Run" button)

Comment: Have a look at comment formatting help http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: OK thanks, the error is:  
Error occurred during initialization of VM  
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ref/FinalReference

Comment: Here the solution of your problem may be found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455236/eclipse-error-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-ref-finalreference

Comment: He start with "Find Running configurations -> java application", and I didn't really understand where I'm supposed to Find "Running configuration"..

Comment: Right click on the project -> Run As -> Run Configurations

Comment: Ahhh almost working! Huge thank you but still there's a little error.. "Error: Could not find or load main class Check"

Comment: Do you have `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: I guess no... Or I just can't find it?  
Because I didn't create one, but I supposed there's already one

Comment: @vasart Are you here? I found the AndroidManifest.xml, I searched for something that mentions "Check" instead of "Main" but I didn't find..