# Error occurred during initialization of VM (java.lang.StackOverflowError) in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Today I suddenly started encountering

```
Error occurred during initialization of VMjava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ref/FinalReference
```

in Eclipse Indigo. I followed [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=345) and also I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455236/eclipse-error-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-ref-finalreference) and
now I am getting:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I am building an Android application using Eclipse Java EE IDE.

EDIT: I don't know why it caused the problem but now I am able to run my activity by going through run-run configurations-android application-run.

Comment: This problem is similar to 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197708/what-causes-a-java-lang-stackoverflowerror.

Comment: What VM did it fail to initialize?  It happens suddenly when you do *what*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem persist due to JVM. If you will give command like java -version. It gives same problem.

If you want to start eclipse.exe by means of the following :

```
E:\softwaredownload\eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32\eclipse>eclipse -vm "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```